# How do I delete a hash out of an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The big picture is, I am taking the code below, which produces something like a windows tasklist. but I want to filter out the users system, local service and network service. then filter out the columns arch, session and path.

```
print_line
processes = @client.sys.process.get_processes
process_list = processes.to_table('Header' => "%bld %dmag Target Process Info:\n", 'Indent' => 4)
```

so far i got the users out, but im stuck on removing the hashes with the keys arch session and path.
here is the output in raw format.

```
[
  {"pid"=>0, "ppid"=>0, "name"=>"[System Process]", "path"=>"", "session"=>4294967295, "user"=>"", "arch"=>""}, 
  {"pid"=>456, "ppid"=>320, "name"=>"explorer.exe", "path"=>"C:\\WINDOWS\\Explorer.EXE", "session"=>0, "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator", "arch"=>"x86"}, 
  {"pid"=>544, "ppid"=>204, "name"=>"TPAutoConnect.exe", "path"=>"C:\\Program Files\\VMware\\VMware Tools\\TPAutoConnect.exe", "session"=>0, "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator", "arch"=>"x86"}, 
  {"pid"=>1096, "ppid"=>456, "name"=>"vmtoolsd.exe", "path"=>"C:\\Program Files\\VMware\\VMware Tools\\vmtoolsd.exe", "session"=>0, "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator", "arch"=>"x86"}, 
  {"pid"=>180, "ppid"=>456, "name"=>"rundll32.exe", "path"=>"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\rundll32.exe", "session"=>0, "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator", "arch"=>"x86"}, 
  {"pid"=>1208, "ppid"=>724, "name"=>"logon.scr", "path"=>"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\logon.scr", "session"=>0, "user"=>"CLINE\\Administrator", "arch"=>"x86"}
]
```

Here is my code so far.

```
print_line
processes = @client.sys.process.get_processes
blacklist = ["NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM", "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE", "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"]
filtered = processes.reject {|h| blacklist.include? h['user']}
print_status (filtered)
```

also the original had the output using the to_table but I seemed to have broke that?

Comment: Your code isn't displaying in an easily read format.  Can you clarify this?  One way to delete elements in a hash--which seems to be what you are asking-- is to write:   myhash.delete("my_element")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, My Understanding is that you want

`pid`, `ppid`, `name`, `user`.

Using [ActiveSupport](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-hash), you can just slice them in-place:

```
processes = @client.sys.process.get_processes
blacklist = ["NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM", "NT AUTHORITY\\LOCAL SERVICE", "NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE"]
filtered = processes.map!{|i| i.slice!("pid", "ppid", "name", "user")}.reject {|h| blacklist.include? h['user']}
print_status (filtered)
```

Is what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your answer was great, thank you.  So now when I try to print with the filtered.to_table I get a error that says "undefined method 'to_table'" is this because the original array has been manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Hash#reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) to delete key-value pairs that satisfy some condition from a Hash to get a new Hash.

```
filtered.map{|p| p.reject{|k, _| %w(arch session path).include?(k)} }
```

Other options are `Hash#reject!`, `Hash#delete`